# Automatically setting registry value (executionpolicy) so I can run a powershell script via Python

Tags: python, powershell, registry

I'm trying to run a powershell script from Python.
So I have this code here:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe","C:\\Users\\Someone\\Documents\\Scripts\\Script.ps1"])
```

But when I do that, I get

```
cannot be loaded because running scripts 
is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at ...
```

I did some researching online and found that I needed to find

> ExecutionPolicy

in

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell

and I need to modify it to

> Unrestricted

So now, my goal is to have my Python code automatically check for this and set this as Unrestricted or create a new ExecutionPolicy with Unrestricted value (this was the case for my computer).

I'm really not sure where or how to attempt this.

Comment: You can also modify the ExecutionPolicy through Powershell directly: `Set-ExecutionPolicy <policy-level> -Scope <permission-scope> -Force`, where `<policy-level>` is something like "RemoteSigned", "Unrestricted", etc, and `<permission-scope>` is something like "CurrentUser", "LocalMachine" etc. Note that you might only be able to change certain scopes as admin or through Group Policy though.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to see if I can automate as many possible steps as possible and combine it all into 1. But I've had no luck so far. The powershell scripts seem to run if I right click and run it in powershell, but not from what I have in Python. I found that it was easier to modify the registry via powershell than Python where I am writing everything else.